# How do I obtain and save a currently logged in user id using php on my website?

Tags: php, authentication

I'm developing a login system for a new website I'm developing and someone advised me to save the user id instead of username in $_SESSION, I don't really know how to obtain the id from database, can someone please show me a code to do it??

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
login_user($username,$password);
$_SESSION['userid'] = $m_result;
}
```

This is the login_user function

```
function login_user($username, $password) {
global $db;
$login = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE password = '$password' AND username = '$username' LIMIT 1");
$m_result = $login->fetch_assoc();
if(!$m_result) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [looking for PHP login script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726666/looking-for-php-login-script)

Comment: [`<?php session_start(); $_SESSION['var'] = "var";` There.](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

Comment: @SteveLacy I don't think _"closed as not a real question"_ looks like a very good duplicate.

Comment: Fred, I know how to save inside $_SESSION, I just want to be able to obtain the id of a particular user from the database

Comment: Oh, the plot thickens now. plus no code to work with.

Comment: why you need an user_id in a session it's already in a database..

Comment: Please provide all relevant code and be more specific in your question

Comment: `$_SESSION['var'] = $row['id'];` there. *How's that, better?*

Comment: you now have an "answer" to work with. Ask them now.

Comment: @Fred-ii- . I don't think I need to provide a code, but if you require it in order to be able to answer me, I'll post a code

Comment: no, it's ok. You have an answer below.

Comment: _I don't really know how to obtain the id from database, can someone please show me a code to do it_ Then you need to do some research, some book reading, some tutorial finding, some experimentation. Also some explaining as to how you got this job in the first place

Comment: @RiggsFolly, it's a personal project

Comment: Ok so you dont need to explain how you got the job. The rest still applies, SO is not a free coding or tutorial service.

Comment: @RiggsFolly , I wouldn't ask if it's not urgent and of the utmost importance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login info has to be saved somewhere. If you are not saving it in the cookies with `$_SESSION` (please don't do that), then you are going to need to save the login information into a database like MySQL or PostgreSQL.

- Download MAMP (Mac) or WAMP (Windows)
- Included in that download is PHPMyAdmin. Open it up and create a database.
- Write your php code to save and retrieve info to and from the database.

I realize what I just shared with you might be a bit tough, so I found a page that might begin to help. Please review this page: http://forums.devshed.com/php-faqs-stickies-167/program-basic-secure-login-system-using-php-mysql-891201.html

Also, please feel free to ask more questions as you may have them.

Comment: I use XAMPP. The page is actually good. I'm trying to build a page like Facebook's newsfeed and I needed the user_id to be able to save in another table for a particular user